# URL for raw image on a GitHub private repository includes a "token" parameter, is this token just for that single file?

Tags: github

Clicking the "Raw" link on GitHub for an image in a private repository includes a token, like this:

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/iron-io/abc/master/docs/images/myimage.png?token=AAEoMm...XYZ
```

Is that token safe to share/commit?  Is it just for that one file?

Comment: do you have any info regarding this i changed repo from public to private and it is not showing any more

Comment: I actually think it expires rather quickly, so it can only be used for a short time. Don't quote me on that, that's just what I recall from a year ago.